# Importing excel sheet to database.

Tags: database, excel, file-upload, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have prepared code to read the excel sheet using apache poi and thereafter I created a bean which holds the data of the excel record(single row). 
Problem is my excel sheet is present in project directory. I want to import the excel sheet from the external to the project directory. 
Someone help me with the code of importing excel sheet from outside to the project directory. 
I have used spring boot and apache poi.

Comment: You have required to save your excel sheet in .csv file and you easly import in your database

Comment: I have alreAdy read the excel file and have the code to store in the database. Problem is I have placed manually the excel sheet in the project directory. Instead I want to import it to the project directory with some ui.

Comment: You Use Which Database system

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL  database

Comment: You make a import system and easily import your database

Comment: Import system ? What does that mean ? Bro

Comment: If You are  developer you make a import csv system in php and easly import your all data in one time

Comment: I am not familiar with the php. I know java

Comment: ok You make import csv system in java and easily Your work done

Comment: Okay.. I will try  thanks for the help

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/ You Read This link

Comment: this link have all detail how can you make Import csv section in java

Comment: Yeah sure.. thanks bro